# Create Like-Gate for page

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I've created a Facebook page and I want to add a so called Like-Gate for it. The problem is that the page is with timeline and every tutorial I've found so far is for the old Facebook pages. Is there a way to create a like gate with the new pages?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First you have to create a general facebook application:
https://developers.facebook.com/apps

After that, you can add the application (with fan gate logic) as `Page Tab` to your site.
Here the official facebook tutorial for page tabs:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/

> When a user selects your Page Tab, you will receive the signed_request parameter with one additional parameter, page. This parameter contains a JSON object with an id (the page id of the current page), admin (if the user is a admin of the page), and liked (if the user has liked the page). As with a Canvas Page, you will not receive all the user information accessible to your app in the signed_request until the user authorizes your app.

Comment: does that require the user add the tab as an application?  Will it prompt the user for permissions when navigating to the tab?  If so is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 2):

You will need to create an app for your page, and use the Facebook PHP SDK. This code worked for me:

```
<?php
require 'facebook.php';

$app_id = "APPID";
$app_secret = "APPSECRET";
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
'appId' => $app_id,
'secret' => $app_secret,
'cookie' => true
));
$signed_request = $facebook->getSignedRequest();
$like_status = $signed_request["page"]["liked"];
?>
```

Then include `<?php if ($like_status) { ?>` before your HIDDEN content.

```
<?php } else { ?>  In between your HIDDEN content and content for non-likers.
```

And lastly close off the content with to close the IF statement:

```
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged (links tend to get stale over time).
Please consider editing your answer and adding a synopsis here.

Comment: Ok, thanks, sorry I am new to this :) Will edit it.

Comment: Speaking of which, the link went stale.

Comment: Well spotted, I have removed as I have took the blog down anyway :)