# Check if visitor of my website likes a facebook page

Tags: facebook

I am in the process of making a band website. I have a download of a song but I want it only to be available to the user if they have liked the bands Facebook page. I am aware there are similar questions to this already on here. I have tried some of them and they don't work, also none of them are very clear. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

There are more than enough results which answer your question, for example [Create Like-Gate for page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9886132/create-like-gate-for-page)

The most simple way to create this is using a `Page Tab` app (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) and parsing the `signed_request` (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/signed-request/) Facebook is sending when the page Tab is accessed.

The `page` object within the `signed_request` contains a field called liked which indicates whether the actual user liked the Page or not.

Comment: Sorry I don't think I was very clear. I am making my own website not connected with facebook, it is not an app or a facebook page. I want to know if an unrelated facebook page has been liked by the visitor of my website. I hope that is more clear

Comment: This is not possible, no way. To request the likes of a FB User, you need the "user_likes" permission, which can only be gathered by an FB app (or you can use the method I explained before).

Comment: Have a look at https://www.facebook.com/ookaymusic/app_190322544333196?ref=ts That's what I described in my answer.